# How can I auto increment the C# assembly version via our CI platform (Hudson)?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, versioning

Myself and my group are horrendous at incrementing assembly version numbers and we frequently ship assemblies with 1.0.0.0 versions.  Obviously, this causes a lot of headaches.

We're getting a lot better with our practices via our [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) platform and I'd really like to set it up to auto increment the values within the `assemblyinfo.cs` file so that the versions of our assemblies are auto updated with the code changes in that assembly.

I had previously setup (before we found [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29)) a way to increment the value through either `msbuild` or the command line (can't remember), but with Hudson, that will update the SVN repository and trigger ANOTHER build. That would result in a slow infinite loop as Hudson polls SVN every hour.

Is having Hudson increment the version number a bad idea? What would be an alternative way to do it?

Ideally, my criteria for a solution would be one that:

- Increments the build number in `assemblyinfo.cs` before a build
- Only increments the build number in assemblies that have changed.  This may not be possible as Hudson wipes out the project folder every time it does a build
- Commits the changed assemblyinfo.cs into the code repository (currently [VisualSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN))
- Does not cause Hudson to trigger a new build the next time it scans for changes

Working this out in my head, I could easily come up with a solution to most of this through batch files / commands, but all of my ideas would cause Hudson to trigger a new build the next time it scans.  I'm not looking for someone to do everything for me, just point me in the right direction, maybe a technique to get Hudson to ignore certain SVN commits, etc.

Everything I've found so far is just an article explaining how to get the version number automatically incremented, nothing takes into account a CI platform that could be spun into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A simple alternative is to let the C# environment increment the assembly version for you by setting the version attribute to `major.minor.*` (as described in the AssemblyInfo file template.)

You may be looking for a more comprehensive solution, though.

**EDIT** (Response to the question in a comment):

From `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: I've never come across this before, could you go into a little bit more detail about what it does.  Does it only function within one IDE or does it work across a whole team of developers with a CI platform?

Comment: ahhh I have seen that before, that may be an acceptable solution but the # built isn't stored within subversion etc.  I have Hudson setup to archive the files and in that way it is stored so that might be acceptable.  I will have to do some more research into how that mechanism works, thanks!

You wouldn't know how it determines what to put in as values, would you?

Comment: See my answer below for the answer to your question.  The values are determined based on the build time.

Comment: Wow, I think this will work.  Not sure how we overlooked such a simple solution

Comment: Hope it does, glad I could help.  Why do something the hard way when the easy, fast way is also the right way?  :)

Comment: Seems like the best solution seeing as there is a comment in the AssemblyInfo.cs file from Microsoft directing to use it.

Comment: Now how to get this value inside a gitlab pipeline....

Answer (score 66):

Here's what I did, for stamping the AssemblyFileVersion attribute.

Removed the AssemblyFileVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs

Add a new, empty, file called AssemblyFileInfo.cs to the project.

Install the [MSBuild community tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) toolset on the hudson build machine or as a [NuGet dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks) in your project.

Edit the project (csproj) file , it's just an msbuild file, and add the following.

Somewhere there'll be a `<PropertyGroup>` stating the version. Change that so it reads e.g.

```
 <Major>1</Major>
 <Minor>0</Minor>
 <!--Hudson sets BUILD_NUMBER and SVN_REVISION -->
 <Build>$(BUILD_NUMBER)</Build>
 <Revision>$(SVN_REVISION)</Revision>
```

Hudson provides those env variables you see there when the project is built on hudson (assuming it's fetched from subversion).

At the bottom of the project file, add

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets')" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets')">
    <Message Text="Version: $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" />
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" OutputFile="AssemblyFileInfo.cs" AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" AssemblyConfiguration="$(Configuration)" Condition="$(Revision) != '' " />
  </Target>
```

This uses the MSBuildCommunityTasks to generate the AssemblyFileVersion.cs to include an AssemblyFileVersion attribute before the project is built. You could do this for any/all of the version attributes if you want.

The result is, whenever you issue a hudson build, the resulting assembly gets an AssemblyFileVersion of 1.0.HUDSON_BUILD_NR.SVN_REVISION e.g. 1.0.6.2632 , which means the 6'th build # in hudson, buit from the subversion revision 2632.

Comment: So just to update this: The method works for C#. I've been using it for some time.  But C++ assemblies (i.e. C++/CLI) are still a problem.  As far as I can tell, the AssemblyInfo task doesn't produce valid C++.
Also, I think this method has a slight downside in that it's a bit opaque for other developers to understand what's happening. Too bad you can't push version numbers directly into MSBuild as a property...

Comment: @CJBrew You could just create a small .bat file that produces the C++ code for the AssemblyInfo, and have msbuild kick off that scipt. I'm not sure what you mean by pushing it as a property, you could certainly stuff the version strings in any property you like - you don't need to use the major/minor/build/revision that I used here.

Comment: Is anything gained using this route vs. just commenting out the AssemblyFileVersion and let it get set to match [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] automatically?

Comment: @ColeChamberlain That'll auto increment if you build it from visual studio on your own PC, not from Hudson - and there's no relation to the version number and a particular build and source code revision.

Answer (score 42):

Here is an elegant solution that requires a little work upfront when adding a new project but handles the process very easily.

The idea is that each project links to a Solution file that only contains the assembly version information.  So your build process only has to update a single file and all of the assembly versions pull from the one file upon compilation.

Steps:

1. Add a class to you solution file *.cs file, I named min SharedAssemblyProperties.cs
2. Remove all of the cs information from that new file
3. Cut the assembly information from an AssemblyInfo file:
   [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
   [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
4. Add the statement "using System.Reflection;" to the file and then paste data into your new cs file (ex SharedAssemblyProperties.cs)
5. Add an existing item to you project (wait... read on before adding the file)
6. Select the file and before you click Add, click the dropdown next to the add button and select "Add As Link".
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 for all existing and new projects in the solution

When you add the file as a link, it stores the data in the project file and upon compilation pulls the assembly version information from this one file.

In you source control, you add a bat file or script file that simply increments the SharedAssemblyProperties.cs file and all of your projects will update their assembly information from that file.

Comment: thanks, Mark.  Sorry for the dead link, it turns out that community server isn't that easy to move.  I should search for help on that topic...

Answer (score 11):

Hudson can be configured to ignore changes to certain paths and files so that it does not prompt a new build.

On the job configuration page, under **Source Code Management**, click the **Advanced** button. In the **Excluded Regions** box you enter one or more regular expression to match exclusions.

For example to ignore changes to the *version.properties* file you can use:

```
/MyProject/trunk/version.properties
```

This will work for languages other than C# and allows you to store your version info within subversion.

Comment: Hudson can also ignore commits from certain users or not trigger a build depending on the commit message. This way you can ignore all commits from Hudson.

Answer (score 10):

.NET does this for you.  In your AssemblyInfo.cs file, set your assembly version to major.minor.* (for example: 1.0.*).

When you build your project the version is auto generated.

The build and revision numbers are generated based on the date, using the unix epoch, I believe.  The build is based on the current day, and the revision is based on the number of seconds since midnight.

Comment: <ring, ring> "hello, product support how may i help?"
<customer> "i have an error"
<support> "ok, what version are you running?"
<customer> "version one point two revision eight five two five three seven four build seven four six three five two nine..."
<support> "hold on, just typing that it... hmmm... please repeat the version numbers, we dont seem to have that build and revision listed..." - GRRR!

Comment: haha nice comment. I'm not a fan of that incrementing system either :p

Comment: Autoincrement in visual studio seriously sucks.

Comment: @Jimbo: While we all agree that your comment was funny, in practice it does not matter. When you speak about your VS installation, do you have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or VS2008 9.0.30729.1 SP? Using autoincrement build numbers is a very common scheme and can be very easily "fixed" by incrementing the major/minor version numbers when a release build comes out.

Comment: highest we have gone with a build number is 678 before resetting back to 0 for a increase in minor revision(of course cruisecontrol, it seemed easier to reset than hudson as in cruisecontrol, you just went in and saved it back to 0 in the project, but everything else in hudson is better)

Answer (score 8):

I've never actually seen that 1.0.* feature work in VS2005 or VS2008. Is there something that needs to be done to set VS to increment the values?

If AssemblyInfo.cs is hardcoded with 1.0.*, then where are the real build/revision stored?

After putting 1.0.* in AssemblyInfo, we can't use the following statement because ProductVersion now has an invalid value - it's using 1.0.* and not the value assigned by VS:

```
Version version = new Version(Application.ProductVersion);
```

Sigh - this seems to be one of those things that everyone asks about but somehow there's never a solid answer. Years ago I saw solutions for generating a revision number and saving it into AssemblyInfo as part of a post-build process.  I hoped that sort of dance wouldn't be required for VS2008.  Maybe VS2010?

Comment: You have to remove the AssemblyFileVersion.  Other than that, its working out awesome for us, the accepted answer that is.

Comment: Yes, removing AssemblyFileVersion allows the version to update, and no more errors with Version. Nice.

Note: two Build operations only increment the revision once, but if you ReBuild the revision is updated.

As ktrauberman said, it looks like the build.revision = date.time, which explains why the data isn't stored anywhere except in the assembly.

Now I need to get a standard MSI Setup to generate a new ProductCode when the primary output project updates. Setups don't allow for revision, only build. I want to install over an existing installation to do an update. Need to research.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming one might also do this with a [text template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) where you create the assembly attributes in question on the fly from the environment like AssemblyVersion.tt does below.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
var build = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER");
build = build == null ? "0" : int.Parse(build).ToString();
var revision = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SVN_REVISION");
revision = revision == null ? "0" : int.Parse(revision).ToString();    
#>
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.<#=build#>.<#=revision#>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.<#=build#>.<#=revision#>")]
```

Answer (score 3):

As a continuation of MikeS's answer I wanted to add that VS + Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK needs to be installed for this to work, and you need to  modify the project file as well. Should also be mentioned I use Jenkins as build server running on a windows 2008 R2 server box with version module, where I get the BUILD_NUMBER.

My Text Template file version.tt looks like this

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
var build = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER");
build = build == null ? "0" : int.Parse(build).ToString();
var revision = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("_BuildVersion");
revision = revision == null ? "5.0.0.0" : revision;    
#>
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("<#=revision#>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("<#=revision#>")]
```

I have the following in the Property Groups

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

after import of Microsoft.CSharp.targets, I have this (dependant of where you install VS

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

On my build  server I then have the following script to run the text transformation before the actual build, to get the last changeset number on TFS

```
set _Path="C:\Build_Source\foo"

pushd %_Path% 
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /Version:W > bar
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%foo in ('findstr /R "^[0-9][0-9]*" bar') do set _BuildVersion=5.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%.%%foo
del bar
popd

echo %BUILD_NUMBER%
echo %_BuildVersion%
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyJob\workspace\MyProject
MSBuild MyProject.csproj /t:TransformAll 
...
<rest of bld script>
```

This way I can keep track of builds AND changesets, so if I haven't checked anything in since last build, the last digit should not change, however I might have made changes to the build process, hence the need for the second last number. Of course if you make multiple check-ins before a build you only get the last change reflected in the version. I guess you could concatenate of that is required.

I'm sure you can do something fancier and call TFS directly from within the tt Template, however this works for me.

I can then get my version at runtime like this

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
return fvi.FileVersion;
```

Answer (score 2):

So, we have a project with one solution that contains several projects that have assemblies with different version numbers.

After investigating several of the above methods, I just implemented a build step to run a Powershell script that does a find-and-replace on the AssemblyInfo.cs file. I still use the 1.0.* version number in source control, and Jenkins just manually updates the version number before msbuild runs.

```
dir **/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs | %{ (cat $_) | %{$_ -replace '^(\s*)\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)\.\*"\)', "`$1[assembly: AssemblyVersion(`"`$2.$build`")"} | Out-File $_ -Encoding "UTF8" }
dir **/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs | %{ (cat $_) | %{$_ -replace '^(\s*)\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\("(.*)\.\*"\)', "`$1[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(`"`$2.$build`")"} | Out-File $_ -Encoding "UTF8" }
```

I added the -Encoding "UTF8" option because git started treating the .cs file as binary files if I didn't. Granted, this didn't matter, since I never actually commit the result; it just came up as I was testing.

Our CI environment already has a facility to associate the Jenkins build with the particular git commit (thanks Stash plugin!), so I don't worry that there's no git commit with the version number attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution doesn't require the addition of external tools or scripting languages --it's pretty much guaranteed to work on your build machine.  I solve this problem in several parts.  First, I have created a BUILD.BAT file that converts the Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER parameter into an environment variable.  I use Jenkins's "Execute Windows batch command" function to run the build batch file by entering the following information for the Jenkins build:

```
     ./build.bat --build_id %BUILD_ID% -build_number %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

In the build environment, I have a build.bat file that starts as follows:

```
     rem build.bat
     set BUILD_ID=Unknown
     set BUILD_NUMBER=0
     :parse_command_line
     IF NOT "%1"=="" (
         IF "%1"=="-build_id" (
             SET BUILD_ID=%2
             SHIFT
             )
         IF "%1"=="-build_number" (
             SET BUILD_NUMBER=%2
             SHIFT
         )
         SHIFT
         GOTO :parse_command_line
     )
     REM your build continues with the environmental variables set
     MSBUILD.EXE YourProject.sln
```

Once I did that, I right-clicked on the project to be built in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer pane and selected Properties, select Build Events, and entered the following information as the Pre-Build Event Command Line, which automatically creates a .cs file containing build number information based on current environment variable settings:

```
     set VERSION_FILE=$(ProjectDir)\Properties\VersionInfo.cs
     if !%BUILD_NUMBER%==! goto no_buildnumber_set
     goto buildnumber_set
     :no_buildnumber_set
     set BUILD_NUMBER=0
     :buildnumber_set
     if not exist %VERSION_FILE% goto no_version_file
     del /q %VERSION_FILE%
     :no_version_file
     echo using System.Reflection; >> %VERSION_FILE%
     echo using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; >> %VERSION_FILE%
     echo using System.Runtime.InteropServices; >> %VERSION_FILE%
     echo [assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%.1")] >> %VERSION_FILE%
     echo [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%.1")] >> %VERSION_FILE%
```

You may need to adjust to your build taste.  I build the project manually once to generate an initial Version.cs file in the Properties directory of the main project.  Lastly, I manually include the Version.cs file into the Visual Studio solution by dragging it into the Solution Explorer pane, underneath the Properties tab for that project.  In future builds, Visual Studio then reads that .cs file at Jenkins build time and gets the correct build number information out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler mechanism.  It simply involves the addition of a Windows Batch command task build step before the MSBuild step and the use of a simple find and replace program (FART).

The Batch Step

```
fart --svn -r AssemblyInfo.cs "[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.0.0\")]" "[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%.%SVN_REVISION%\")]"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit /b 1
fart --svn -r AssemblyInfo.cs "[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(\"1.0.0.0\")]" "[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(\"1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%.%SVN_REVISION%\")]"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

If you are using source control other than svn change the --svn option for the appropriate one for your scm environment.

[Download Fart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/files/latest/download)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a couple of methods using a prebuild Powershell script(https://gist.github.com/bradjolicoeur/e77c508089aea6614af3) to increment on each successful build then in Global.asax I've going something like this:

```
  // We are using debug configuration, so increment our builds.
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
      string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                                       .GetName()
                                                       .Version
                                                       .ToString();

      var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"svn", "commit -m \"Version: " + version + "\n \"");
      psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\CI\Projects\myproject";
      Process.Start(psi); 
  }
```

I still think the whole process is overcomplicated and I'm going to look into a more efficient method of achieving the same result.  I wanted this mainly for passing the version into SVN and then into Jenkin's without too many addtional tools.