# NAnt and build version

Tags: nant

I use Nant for automating ClickOnce build. So after building the application I need to know what is its version (for purpose of folder creation). Also I need build autoincrementing.

For building I use `msbuild.exe /t:publish`

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use your source code repository revision number/hash as that is often used when using subversion or git repositories.

You can also make use of a buildserver like cruisecontrol (ccnet) this will do this build version incrementing for you.

Comment: I use nant for publishing. So if I change something witout check in into source safe, publish it, then I see a mistake, fix it and publish again. (note that I nevere check in it in source safe, so version number in source control didn't change but it changed in application)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you would like to do version detection/management with minimal effort.

Why don't you use AssemblyInfo auto-increment capabilities. Putting `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` into your `AssemblyInfo.cs` will increment the build number with every build. Find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126880/how-can-i-auto-increment-the-c-assembly-version-via-our-ci-platform-hudson/1126895#1126895).

After compilation you can detect the assembly version via [NAnt function `assemblyname::get-version`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/assemblyname.get-version%28System.Reflection.AssemblyName%29.html):

```
assemblyname::get-version(assemblyname::get-assembly-name('MyAssembly.dll'))
```

**Update:**
If you can't use Assembly info auto-increment capabilities, you might let NAnt create AssemblyInfo.cs with every build using [NAntContrib's `<version>`-task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/version.html).

```
<loadtasks assembly="C:\PathToNAntContibTasks\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
<target name="assemblyinfo" description="generates AssemblyInfo.cs">
  <property
    name="working.dir"
    value="C:\src\foo" />
  <property
    name="build.number.path"
    value="${path::combine(working.dir, 'build.number')}" />
  <echo
    file="${build.number.path}"
    message="0.0.0.0"
    unless="${file::exists(build.number.path)}" />
  <version
    buildtype="Increment"
    path="${build.number.path}"/>
  <foreach
    item="File"
    property="assemblyinfo.path">
    <in>
      <items>
        <include name="${path::combine(working.dir, '**\AssemblyInfo.cs')}" />
      </items>
    </in>
    <do>
      <asminfo output="${assemblyinfo.path}" language="CSharp">
        <imports>
          <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
        </imports>
        <attributes>
          <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="${buildnumber.version}" />
        </attributes>
      </asminfo>
    </do>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: Because when you use msbuild /t:publish it doesn't increment version even you mark the assembly by this flag. Thank you for NAnt function that is what I need.