# Modify AssemblyInfo.cs with NAnt instead of Creating a new one

Tags: nant, assemblyinfo, assemblyversions, assemblyversionattribute

I've used  in NAnt to create AssemblyInfo files from scratch. However, in this case, I would like to just modify one line in the file (AssemblyVersion).  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860985/nant-and-build-version