# Write a batch script to edit text in a .cs file

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, c#

I wonder if anyone knows how to write a batch script to edit some text in a .cs file.
What I want to do is change "AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")" "AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.x")" where x++ for every time the job in jenkins is being built.
Best Regards Jan

Comment: I assume you're running jenkins on windows. I'm not a 100% sure, but I would bet that you can do that with powershell.

Comment: There are better tools for this than `cmd`, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3517135/34148

Comment: The problem is that everything is built on a windows server that acts as a slave to hudson. Hudson on the other hand is a linux server.
Just tried to build everything directly on hudson (using the msbuild plugin) and it works fine except for the assemblyfileinfo.cs file which is completely empty. I guess this is because I have to install MSBuildTasks on hudson, and I haven't got a solution for that atm.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use only a batch script for this? You could also use **Execute Groovy Script** option and write some simple groovy script to achieve this

```
file = new File("folder/path/myfile.cs")
fileText = file.text;
fileText = fileText.replaceAll(srcExp, replaceText);
file.write(fileText);
```

You can also use the availabe environment variables from your jenkins job to construct your replace text. These variables will be present at /env-vars.html

Comment: how can I iterate over jenkins varaibles to replace each of them with its value in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from "batch-file automation" - will only cause you grief.
(for a starter, different versions of Windows support a different set of batch-commands)

You should incorporate the build-number in the script as an *Environment Variable* -
use either the "built-in" `%BUILD_NUMBER%` parameter or set your own format with
the **[Formatted Version-Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)** .

If you do need to edit that 'CS' file, I suggest using either **Perl** or **PowerShell**.

Cheers