# Retrieve all jenkins parameters to iterate in groovy code

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746197/write-a-batch-script-to-edit-text-in-a-cs-file) answer, I would like to iterate over all the properties in jenkins job and replace with their value in the job in build step.

e..g.

```
file = new File("folder/path/myfile.cs")
fileText = file.text;
fileText = fileText.replaceAll("parameter", "parametervalue");
file.write(fileText);
```

I saw an example to resolve one param like this:

```
build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("myparameter")
```

But I need

> 1. To iterate over all of them
> 2. To do it in Build step (after pulling from Source Code) so in the current build.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a sample groovy code that you can use with the [scriptler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin), that I suggest to use. This code can correctly read the Environment variables that are set in any Jenkins job:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def env = build.getEnvironment()
def buildNumber = env.get("BUILD_NUMBER")
```

In case you want to read the Build Parameters (you have a parameterized build and need access to those variables), you need to use the previous code and add the following:

```
def bparams = build.getBuildVariables()
def myBuildParam = bparams.get("MY_BUILD_PARAMETER")
```

after you read them, you can write them to your file, in a build step occurring after the git cloning.

Comment: BUILD_NUMBER is an environment variable available in any job. How to read it is written in the code I posted, if using the groovy scriptler plugin. The code you posted is only usable from the build flow plugin. Basically each plugin has its own api exposed, therefore you have a different syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I may express my question more.
The build has build parameters  - I need to retrieve them. is it considered as build environment variables?

Comment: I am looking for a way to iterate over all the environment dynamically and inject them

Comment: Ok, I extended the answer so you can now read whatever you want :). To iterate over all of them, you can just take the object that you read with groovy and do what you want (that's trivial).